# when specifying a div width, is it relative to the size of the window or the parent object?

Tags: html, css

honestly, the title says it all. I have a parent div that contains two other divs. The left div shouls be 20% of the width and the right div should be 80 percent of the width, but I am gettting some weird behavior, so if someone could enlighten me on the behavior of div widths in html?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Your idea is correct generally, I need to see your HTML

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you have the CSS set for these elements.

If the element is set to `position: relative`, it will be positioned relative to its parent container.

If the element is set to `position: absolute`, it can be positioned on the page anywhere, regardless of where other things are positioned on the page.

If you're having positioning issues, it will probably help to set this attribute for these elements in CSS.

More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: You are wrong. Position relative positions an elemen relative to its normal position, position absolute does what you wrote about relative - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position. An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor

Answer (score 0):

If by weired you mean like this:
[image]
(Red is parent, blue is first with 20 percent width, cyan is second with 80 percent width)
Then you should use `float: left` to get them to aligned with the parent.
Then it becomes aligned like the picture below:
[image]

```
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text" style="background: red;">
    <div style="background: blue; height: 20px; width: 20%; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background: cyan; height: 20px; width: 80%; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```